# Is it possible to modify a class for specific element?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using C# I have a disabled button like that

```
<div data-cid="view163" class="pull-right"><a class="btn btn-success btn-large disabled" data-action="proceed" href="#"><span class="btn-content">Continue</span></a></div>
```

Is there a way to change the `a` tag class to be `btn btn-success btn-large` so I can click on the link ?

Comment: If the element is there and clickable, you should be able to click it regardless of the `disabled` class. You might be running into a different issue, like a selector returning a different element, or trying to click it before it becomes visible.

Comment: no it is disabled

Comment: If it's disabled, would this be a valid test to hijack the page like this? Or perhaps this isn't for testing purposes :)

Comment: data entry automation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I see of your html, the button is not actually disabled, it just has a class of 'disabled' however if something in your code is keying off of that, you can use the IJavaScriptExecutor interface of the driver to execute javascript to remove the class. If you have jquery in your website and are using C# to drive selenium it would look like this:

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).Execute("$('a.disabled').removeClass('disabled')");
```

The syntax might not be exactly correct but that is the idea. Of course your selector might vary depending on the rest of your html.

Comment: You would have to use the dom to navigate to the anchor tag and remove the class. It's been so long since I've gone that direction that I don't know off hand how to do it.

Comment: `executeScript(String expr)`